# How to draw matching lines in Java using netbeans IDE

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I am interested in XML schema matching. I use java library XSOM to parse two XML Schemas and display them as trees and find differences between them.

What I ask for is how to draw lines showing the matched nodes of two trees. I already display the two trees using Java swing, but I don't know how to draw lines between the two tree lists.
something like the picture below (edited picture to show the need):

[image: xsd1 and xsd2 tree matching]

Any ideas? thanks